# Event OnChange doesn't fired when I call method LoadFromFile of TSynEdit.Lines

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a project using TSynEdit. I found that when I call `SynEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile()`, event `OnChange` doesn't be fired.

For instance:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, SynEdit, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    SynEdit1: TSynEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SynEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SynEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('unit1.pas');
end;

procedure TForm1.SynEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption:=Caption + '!';
end;

end.
```

In above example, I created a form which have a button and a SynEdit.

How can I make event `OnChange` be fired when `SynEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile()` was called?

Comment: I belive you have to call it you self.

And that is strange because both TMemo and TRichEdit fires the onchange event when you call Lines.LoadFromFile

Comment: I do not have SyncEdit installed here. But As far as I remember, you do it in the same way with TRichEdit: 

  RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('unit6.pas');
  if Assigned(RichEdit1.OnChange) then
    RichEdit1.OnChange(RichEdit1);

Comment: @JensBorrisholt: I'll wait for a better solution

Comment: Have you looked to see if SynEdit's LoadFromFile method actually DOES trigger the OnChange event? It may not. In which case, there IS NO BETTER solution.

Comment: I'll see if I have the time to installe the suite today, then I'll have a look.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to assign all the events handler of a synedit, the best you can get is a notification when the editor is cleared. For example if you test the following code the form caption will be set to 'cleared' after the button click event:

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, SynEdit, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, LazSynEditText;

type
  TSynEditEx = class helper for TSynEdit
    function getTextBuffer: TSynEditStrings;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    SynEdit1: TSynEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure textCleared(sender: TObject);
    procedure textHistoryModified(sender: TObject);
    procedure textBuffChanged(sender: TObject);
    procedure textLineChanged(sender: TObject);
    procedure textEditAction(sender: TObject);
    procedure textModdChanged(sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.lfm}

function TSynEditEx.getTextBuffer: TSynEditStrings;
begin
  exit(TextBuffer);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SynEdit1.getTextBuffer.AddNotifyHandler(senrCleared, @textCleared);
  SynEdit1.getTextBuffer.AddNotifyHandler(senrUndoRedoAdded, @textHistoryModified);
  SynEdit1.getTextBuffer.AddNotifyHandler(senrTextBufferChanged, @textBuffChanged);
  SynEdit1.getTextBuffer.AddNotifyHandler(senrLineChange, @textLineChanged);
  SynEdit1.getTextBuffer.AddNotifyHandler(senrModifiedChanged, @textModdChanged);
end;

procedure TForm1.textModdChanged(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' ModdChanged';
end;

procedure TForm1.textEditAction(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' EditAction';
end;

procedure TForm1.textLineChanged(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' LineChanged';
end;

procedure TForm1.textBuffChanged(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' BuffChanged';
end;

procedure TForm1.textCleared(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' Cleared';
end;

procedure TForm1.textHistoryModified(sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Caption + ' HistoryModified';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SynEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('unit1.pas');
end;
```

So the only solution is to subclass TSynEdit and introduce a custom `LoadFromFile` method and then trigger the `onChange` event inside. AFAIK, based on a short investigation, this is the only way, a bit like this:

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, SynEdit, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, LazSynEditText;

type
  TSynEditEx = class helper for TSynEdit
    procedure LoadFromFile(const aFilename: string);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    SynEdit1: TSynEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SynEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.lfm}

procedure TSynEditEx.LoadFromFile(const aFilename: string);
begin
  Lines.LoadFromFile('unit1.pas');
  if assigned(onChange) then
    onChange(self);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SynEdit1.LoadFromFile('unit1.pas');
end;

procedure TForm1.SynEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  caption := caption + '!';
end;
```

In the real world you wouldn't use a class helper but you'd rather subclass, but I think you should get the idea.

Comment: It is a really short and efficient solution. Thank you.